# changing datatype for a already saved xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read already saved xml's the XML has objects serialized. And I am deserializing to read from file into objects in c#.

```
class Person
{
    public string xyz { get; set; } // This is how an example class looks like.
}
```

Now I have a requirement of changing the data type of this property to EncryptedString type

So now my class looks like

```
class Person
{
    public EncryptedString xyz { get; set; } = new EncryptedString();
}
```

When I deserialize the object and check-in person's instance I get xyz.stringvalue == null .
While if I use to older class structured when xyz is a string type field I get xyz's original value.
Note : EncryptedString is a custom object which takes a string and encrypts it

Comment: Does EncryptedString implements IXmlSerializable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?view=net-5.0 ... if not, I think it should.

Comment: @rene it has the attribute  [Serializable] on top of the class. Also EncryptedString object works fine in case of new objects created and saved and reloaded from XML it's just the files which have them as a string is giving null.

Comment: Serializable is not enough as your person deserailizer expects in `<xyz><encryptedstring>?</encryptedstring></xyz>`  You can debug this by creating a Person instance, serialize it to XML and then compare what you get and what your input is. Once you can serialize to the same format as your input, you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks @rene this didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check [XML versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/version-tolerant-serialization) that seems like the thing you would use.

One way could be to mark your `xyz` with a new version and at the same time create backing property `serialization_xyz` that would be used to deserialization purposes only and on getter will set the value of real `xyz`

Check [Serializations callbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute?view=net-5.0) as well if you are ready to read context manually and don't want to have some workaround fields

Answer (score 0):

```
public string Value
    { //For backward compatibility
        get => null;
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                KeyValue.Value = value;
        }
    }
public EncryptedString KeyValue { get; set; } = new EncryptedString();
```

This one worked for me When I load the file it saves the string value in Encrypted string keyvalue and when it will serialize it back due to value being null it won't store the value element.